# C# MySQL Syntax error in SQL Statement

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this simple method that is supposed to insert a row into a DB. It is throwing an exception.

```
private void AddToLiveQueue(int user_id, bool release = false)
    {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO live_support_queues (user_id, release, created_at, updated_at)";
        sql += " VALUES(?user_id, ?release, ?created_at, ?created_at)";

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?user_id", user_id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?release", release);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?created_at", DateTime.UtcNow);


        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SendEmail email = new SendEmail();
            email.Send(ex.Message + "      " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release, created_at, updated_at) VALUES(70, 0, '2017-09-22 23:00:16.686741', '20' at line 1"
```

[image: Here is the SQL columns]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you debug this, pull the values out and run the statement exactly on the database, what happens?

Comment: the id is auto-generated and is not in the insert statement. the user_is is not auto-generated and is in the insert statement.

Comment: Can you print the SQL generated and post it? That's usually an excellent debug check.

Comment: I cant print the generated SQL statement because i am using parameters. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971267/get-generated-sql-statement-from-mysqlcommand 

But the user_id = 70, the release is 0

Comment: I could be remembering wrong, but I seem to recall AddWithValue() not handling bool arguments well. That said, your error seems to indicate MySQL is having an issue well before it would reach that; is it possible `user_id` or `live_support_queues` have a trailing whitespace in their names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`release` is a reserved word, and needs escaped with ` symbols if used as an identifier.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.

Comment: in future when an a query doesn't run, try to extract the exact query and run it for testing... it will help you quickly solve such issues

Comment: I find the best practice is to delimit all identifiers with the ` ; that way if a new reserved word is added (or a keyword that could cause some ambiguity) you're already covered.